# AWS Beanstalk and not subversioned files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an instance in AWS Beanstalk and use it with git repository.

There is two files outside this repository, config.php and .htaccess.
I could create them with vim, inside the instance via ssh, but when I upload a new version they are erased.

What is the correct way to work with files outside the repository, like db connection and custom configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind Elastic Beanstalk (and other application PaaS's as this isn't unique to Elastic Beanstalk) is that the server the application runs on is in essence stateless. This means that any local changes that you make to the instance will be gone if that instance is replaced.

This can be the case when using AutoScaling Groups that cause instances to be terminated and created based on demand. This can also happen if your instance has issues and is deemed in a bad state.

Thus if you SSH into an EC2 instance, create files, and then push a new version of your application, your instance is tore down, brought back up and the files aren't there anymore.

If you want to persist information that isn't in version control (often application secrets like API keys, credentials, specific configuration, etc.), then one way to do that is to add it to environment variables which you can learn about here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/deploy/envvar.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can leave the .htaccess on git and config info as env vars. But I still have problem, for example, to have a folder to save files uploaded by users and admin-users. I lose it when upload again. Should I save it outside the www folder?

Comment: If your application is accepting uploads and storing them, it would be beneficial to be storing them somewhere long term and distributed such as S3.

Comment: The config files I substitute with env. vars, as @Josh Davis suggests. The files and folder uploaded on running application I could keep adding them in `.gitignore` file. Those are not erased when I upload a new version anymore.

Answer (score 1):

@Josh Davis is correct in saying "The idea behind Elastic Beanstalk (and other application PaaS's as this isn't unique to Elastic Beanstalk) is that the server the application runs on is in essence stateless. This means that any local changes that you make to the instance will be gone if that instance is replaced."

In layman's terms, that means that the server can be rebuilt at any time and any data that was persisted to disk is lost.

If you'd like to persist the above two files without version control then I would suggest using ebextensions >> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html

**Example:**

```
files:
 "/home/ec2-user/myfile" :
   mode: "000755"
   owner: root
   group: root
   source: http://foo.bar/myfile

 "/home/ec2-user/myfile2" :
   mode: "000755"
   owner: root
   group: root
   content: |
     # this is my file
     # with content
```

The first example will download a file from *http://foo.bar/myfile* and create that file and it's contents on the file system in this location */home/ec2-user/myfile*

The second example will create a file with the contents you specify; in this case the file will have # this is my file # with content.

If you use the second option always run is through a YAML validator >> http://www.yamllint.com/